# Getting error when installing bufferutil npm package

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, plesk

I've a problem install my application on my server. Locally everything works fine. The versions of node and npm are the same but I'm still getting this error during my install on the server:

```
91 verbose stack Error: bufferutil@4.0.1 install: `node-gyp-build`
91 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
91 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/plesk/node/12/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:48:18)
91 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
91 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
91 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
```

What can I do? Does someone has an idea?

Installed is node `12.4.0`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm lacking reputation to comment so sorry for a terrible answer.

I had the same problem with a project depending on `socket.io`. My luck is that `bufferutil` is an optional dependency so I just removed it.

In any case `bufferutil` is only used to [mask and unmask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174184/what-is-the-mask-in-a-websocket-frame) data which, AFAICT, is only used for plain http/ws connections (so not https/wss) so it may not be needed in your case.